# jQuery Modal only Opened once after clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

i've some problem that make make head feels so heavy... i've searched for the answer in this forum, but the problem still not solve. 
my problem is i've a button that link to modals. when first time after the page refreshed the modal open while the button clicked. but not for the second time. 
i've check the log and the log said

```
TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function[Learn More].
```

if i refreshed the page, it will only work once, and the second click of the button, the modals not open again...

this is my button HTML view code..

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-labeled" type="button" id="tambahUser" data-toggle = "modal" value="<?= Url::to(['/module/create'],true)?>">
```

this is my modal

```
    <div id="modalSignUpSm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-info">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="tutupModal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Colored Header Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="modalContent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my js code that responsible for handling click event of the button

```
$('#tambahUser').click(function(event){
    $('#modalSignUpSm').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
    })
    .modal('show')
    .find('#modalContent')
    .load($(this).attr('value'));
});

$('#tutupModal').click(function(){
    $('#modalSignUpSm').modal('close');
});
```

this is my controller (i'm using Yii2) of Module/create

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Module();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(Url::to(['/paneladm/pengaturan/module',true]));
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My Question is why the modals only open once and after that, the button stuck..? how to resolve that...

Note: - i'm new on jQuery, and i will very thanks for every answer. 
- i've search on this forum and try to resolve with create a button and every this button clicked will be firing the .modal('close') but still not work

Comment: Try `$('#modalSignUpSm').modal("open");` or use `$('#modalSignUpSm').modal('hide');` instead of close it

Comment: It seems to be an issue bootstrap. Are you using a CDN version or have you downloaded and added the `bootstrap.js` file to your website.

Comment: @RogerRV :thanks for your reply..  i've change it, but it still now work. .modal("open") make modal not open when click the button. and .modal("hide") is still not open when second click...

Comment: @DanPhilip : thanks for your reply... i've using bootstrap.js included with my themes... not add manual nor downloaded.. if it's still issue, any another way to resolve it? that will get the same goal to resolve this problem?

Comment: @NurulHuda Try adding a downloaded local file of `boostrap.js` to your website.

Answer (score 1):

You should **either** use Bootstraps data-attributes to trigger the modal on and off, **or** use trigger via javascript manually. Right now you are trying to do both. See [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp).

So I would remove the bootstrap data-attributes and then make sure your bootstrap script is loaded **before** your own javascript.

Comment: thanks for your reply...
i've change the link to the content of modals bootstrap. in the <button> with attribute **value**. when i change to the url /site/index (no form in this url) the modals always open every i click the button. but when i change to the url /site/contact (form contact models) the button stack again.

note : i use Yii2 PHP Framework